# VSCode 1.18.1 doesn't install extensions from VSIX if offline?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tend to use Visual Studio Code as a text editor on my development machine that doesn't have internet connection. However after updating to 1.18.1 I am unable to install extensions from downloaded VSIX files. If I try to use GUI nothing happens, no errors or warnings and the extension is not installed as the result. When I tried to install extension using command line I get:

```
code --install-extension ms-python.python-0.8.0.vsix
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN marketplace.visualstudio.com:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:33:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:73:26)
```

It seems it tries to connect to the internet, but extension is already downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are running into this VS Code 1.18 bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37973

This should already be fixed in [VS Code insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and should also be fixed in VS Code 1.19 stable once that is released